# calculate item length in outer of map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a json like this

```
var person = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": 20
}, {
    "name": "Samuel",
    "age": 10
}, {
    "name": "Jin",
    "age": 10
}]
```

My desire output is

```
age 10 (2)
- Samuel
- Jin

age 20 (1)
- John
```

I have problem counting the total. I would do

```
ages.map(doList) //where ages is [10,20]

doList(age) {
    persons.filter(p => p.age === age)
    .map(p => {
       p.name
    })
}
```

but how do print out the length of the age group?

Comment: *"I have a json"* - That's not JSON, it's an object. Are you trying to get output based on a separate `ages` array because you wanted to get *only* those ages rather than just summarising whatever ages happened to be in the `person` array?

Comment: @nnnnnn that's not even an object, it's an array of objects

Comment: @A.Lau - Well yes, but an array is a type of object...

Comment: @A.Lau so what is the solution?

Comment: can't you just `.length` the returned filter?

Comment: Further to my previous question,is the output supposed to be just a plain string in the format shown?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, it technically is, and I worded it badly, but calling an array of objects as just another 'object' is more confusing. I probably should just have said, 'it's an array of objects'. It's like calling all functions objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might change your data structure for easier output like.

```
var person = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": 10
}, {
    "name": "Samuel",
    "age": 10
}, {
    "name": "Jin",
    "age": 10
}];



let newArray = [];
person.forEach((p) => {
  let findPreviousIndex = newArray.findIndex((itm) =>{
    return itm.age == p.age;
  });

  if(findPreviousIndex > -1){
    // previous found, push the name
    newArray[findPreviousIndex].names.push(p.name);
  }else{
    // not found. create a new object and push it
    newArray.push({
      "age" : p.age,
      "names" : [].concat(p.name)
    })
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Now, its easy to print your grouped data and easy to find length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to produce the desired output, first using `.reduce()` to set up a `result` object with a property for each age that is an array of names for that age, then mapping over the properties of `result` to create a `formatted` string that gives the specific format in the question:

```js
var person = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": 20
}, {
    "name": "Samuel",
    "age": 10
}, {
    "name": "Jin",
    "age": 10
}]

var result = person.reduce((a, c) => {
  (a[c.age]||(a[c.age]=[])).push(c.name)
  return a
}, {})
console.log(result)

var formatted = Object.keys(result)
  .map(k=>`age ${k} (${result[k].length})\n${result[k].map(n => `- ${n}`).join('\n')}`)
  .join('\n\n')
console.log(formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": 20
}, {
    "name": "Samuel",
    "age": 10
}, {
    "name": "Jin",
    "age": 10
}];

// create a map where the key is the person's age and the value is a list of names
var ageMap = person.reduce(function(result, p) {
    var key = p.age;
    var name = p.name;
    if (result[key]) {
        result[key].push(name);
    } else {
        result[key] = [name];
    }
    return result;
}, {});

// traverse the map and print the names of people grouped by age
Object.keys(ageMap).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = ageMap[key];
    console.log("age " + key + " (" + value.length + ")");
    value.forEach(function(name) {
        console.log("- " + name);
    });
    console.log("");
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njcms8rj/